# How to extract date from text string

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I need to extract the date (**08-01-2021**) from the below string that has no whitespace

```
select 'Date-08-01-2021-Trans-1000008-PH.0000-BA-CR-9999.21' from dual
```

I tried to apply the REGEXP_SUBSTR function as shown below, but using this query I just removed 'Date-'

```
 with x as
    (select 'Date-08-01-2021-Trans-1000008-PH.0000-BA-CR-9999.21' as str
     from dual)
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, 'Date-([^ ]+)',1,1,'i',1)
   FROM x;
```

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are zero-padding the date values so each term has a fixed length and have a fixed prefix so you do not need to use (slow) regular expressions and can just use simple string functions:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE(SUBSTR(value, 6, 10), 'DD-MM-YYYY')
FROM   table_name;
```

*(Note: if you still want it as a string, rather than as a date, then just use `SUBSTR` without wrapping it in `TO_DATE`.)*

For example:

```sql
WITH table_name ( value ) AS (
  SELECT  'Date-08-01-2021-Trans-1000008-PH.0000-BA-CR-9999.21' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT TO_DATE(SUBSTR(value, 6, 10), 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS date_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | DATE_VALUE |
> | --- |
> | 08-JAN-21 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ec223a08bacef56507b33455894a4504)*

---

If the `Date-`  prefix is not going to always be at the start then use `INSTR` to find it:

```sql
WITH table_name ( value ) AS (
  SELECT  'Date-08-01-2021-Trans-1000008-PH.0000-BA-CR-9999.21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  'Trans-1000008-Date-08-02-2021-PH.0000-BA-CR-9999.21' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT TO_DATE(SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, 'Date-') + 5, 10), 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS date_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which outputs:

> | DATE_VALUE |
> | --- |
> | 08-JAN-21 |
> | 08-FEB-21 |

---

If you can have multiple `Date-` substrings and you want to find the one that is either at the start of the string or has a `-` prefix then you may need regular expressions:

```sql
WITH table_name ( value ) AS (
  SELECT  'Date-08-01-2021-Trans-1000008-PH.0000-BA-CR-9999.21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  'TransDate-1000008-Date-08-02-2021-PH.0000-BA-CR-9999.21' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT TO_DATE(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(^|-)Date-(\d\d-\d\d-\d{4})([-.]|$)', 1, 1, 'i', 2),
         'DD-MM-YYYY'
       ) AS date_value
FROM   table_name;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ac9aa054665e6d3f002f4d39f69cf5e1)*

Comment: Thank you for your help, I applied the REGEXP_SUBSTR instead of SUBSTR, because the Date position may be in the middle of the text as it is not fixed. Ex:  `'1003030405-Value date-03-01-2021-BANK-00009.61-000000.91&22.45-PH.0000'`

Comment: @Maram If there is always the `Date-` prefix then you can just use `SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, 'Date-') + 5, 10)` and it will still be faster than regular expressions.

Comment: PERFECT, I just tried your commands it is working with all cases

Answer (score 2):

Just use a more precise regular expression:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, 'Date-([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})', 1, 1, 'i', 1)
FROM x;
```

Or for less accuracy but more conciseness:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, 'Date-([-0-9]{10})', 1, 1, 'i', 1)
```